# Batch processing, crop, flip, change colorprofile and save as PC raw 16

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have encountered a problem when creating several heightmaps for a game.

I have a worldmap that is based on 50x50 terrain tiles. But to save time I need to batch this in case the world ends up looking wierd.

So how can I do:

1. Batch crop my 2500 slices.
2. Flip the crop both horizontally and vertically (this is solving a heightmap problem in Unity).
3. Save the crop as PC RAW 16bit in colorprofile 16bit greyscale.

Or how could I do this:

1. Convert 2500 PNG/JPEG images to PC RAW 16bit in colorprofile 16bit greyscale
2. Flip it both horizontally and vertically.

How could I do otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume from your question that you have one large Photoshop file that is divided into your "tiles" with the slice function.

Since flipping the entire image would ruin your tiles, you would have to run the batch on the individual files instead. So:

1. Save all your slices as PNG (this is the better choice as JPG is lossy) and save them in a folder.
2. Open one of the PNG files in photoshop.
3. Create a new Action from the Actions panel. It will start to record.
4. Perform the steps needed for the tile - convert to greyscale, perform the horizontal/vertical flip, convert the color profile and save as chosen file type.
5. Stop the Action recording.
6. Go to the menu item Automation/Batch and select your new action and select desination folder
7. Alternatively you can go to menu item Automation/Create Droplet and make a droplet with your chosen Action to save on the desktop. You can now simply drop any files you want onto
   it and it will batch your files.

Comment: Thanks! In my head that works like a charm cause it all make sense!